# How to build React.js to multiple folders

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Normally Reactj.js when build, it's will generate into `/build/` folder. what I want is I want to build like this

`/build/a/`
`/build/b/`
`/build/c/`

Do you know how to do it? You can tell me by keywords I will search and research by myself.

Thank you
(English is not my native sorry)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3824

Comment: Not possible, if you don't move files as linked by Just code